# Bituminous paint not curing on chassis

Tags: chassis-paint

I’m restoring a Mitsubishi GTO and I’ve been removing rust from its chassis, then zinc priming, epoxy coating and finally in areas where stones do hit, coating with bituminous coating (3M Schulz to be precise).

In certain areas there was no rust and thus I didn’t remove the original coating (don’t know what it is exactly). In those areas when I sprayed with bituminous over it, it never cured. 3 months later it hasn’t cured and I’ve contacted 3M to ask for advice to which they said that I can try heat to see if it will cure. Heat helped a little bit (made it less tacky) but didn’t fix the problem. This isn’t an issue where I used epoxy mastic and then sprayed with 3M Schulz, in those areas the coating has cured and isn’t tacky.

I don’t know what to do next, one option is obviously to remove it with the grinder, and then prime it, epoxy coat it and then apply Schulz again. Is there another option? Can I remove it with a thinner and then coat the underside with epoxy rather than going back to bare metal?

Has anyone got any experience with bituminous coatings reacting with previous chassis coatings?

Comment: By "bituminous" are you talking about the rubber undercoating 3M sells? Is it cold where you're at?

Comment: It is yes, the asphalt based undercoating, and yes it is cold

Comment: I'm betting once things warm up it will fully cure. The problem may be the frame you put it on is never fully heating when you put your heat gun to it (the 3M product may be blocking this), so the underneath portion of the coating isn't getting warm enough to cure. If you can wait for it to warm up outside so all of the car can warm up, you might be in the clear. If not, you can do what you want at that point to remove/replace as you suggested. Might be worth it to wait a while.

Comment: " Bituminous" implies coal tar ( not asphalt , not rubber ) which may stay soft to flow into any holes and maintain coverage of the steel . But it may just be a name the advertising guy thought sounded good.

Comment: Why is it a problem if it doesn’t cure fully?

Comment: It’s soft when cured but not tacky. The parts that had epoxy mastic underneath cured within two days and got harder and dry. The uncured but is tacky, touching it lifts some off, wiping also lifts it off. If I start driving the car around as it is, the uncured bits will either come off, and won’t offer any protection. I suspect heat has something to do with it because it definitely helped, but I also suspect there’s either a reaction or trapped solvent, because it feels like it’s still soft and moist with solvent where not cured.